# What is the highest number that could be written down in principle using all computers in the world?

Tags: computer-science, big-numbers

I read somewhere in the internet, that the capacity of all computers in the world
 would be about $10^{18}$ bytes.

Does this mean, that in principle, a number with $10^{18}$ digits could be written
 down using all computers in the world ?

I do not know, if the data can be stored because it would have to be on ONE computer
 at the end. This is why I doubt that $10^{18}$ is possible.

On the other hand, $\pi$ has been calculated to more than $10^{12}$ digits. ( I do not
 know the exact value, it could be in the range of $10^{15}$)
 Are these digits availabe on any single computer ?

And finally, if more than a single computer calculated $\pi$, how could they work
 together to manage this task ?

Comment: Notice 1 byte can store more than 1 decimal digits. Or are you talking about base-256 digits?

Comment: Here: $10^{10^{18}}$. I just wrote down a number with *more* than $10^{18}$ digits :-). More seriously though, what do you mean by calculating $\pi$? It's irrational, so there is not enough space in the universe to write down its digits.

Comment: Perhaps the question is not formulated well. I wanted to know how many digits could be handled using all computers in the world and if the digits would all be availabe afterwards. The example with $\pi$ only shows, that apparantly it is possible to handle $10^{13}$ digits or more.

Comment: There are many vague thoughts interwoven in this question.  What does it mean to "write down" a number, especially one that is shared between two computers.  If you insist that a number be stored on one computer, you are limited to the the largest single computer in the world.  In theory you could just keep attaching disk drives if that is acceptable to you.  At the end, it is certainly possible to split computation across multiple computers.  There can be subsidiary calculations that are finally combined into one result.

Comment: A helpful comment. Thanks! (I know that my question is not very concrete, but I am just curious)